# Ext JS - handling custom events

Tags: javascript, events, extjs

I'm trying to get my head around custom events. I want some entities to be listeners, and then be able to fire an event without knowing who is listening.

I have this `afterrender` handler in the main controller, confirmed it is being called and a tab control is "on" for the event `userTimeOut`:

```
// Register components
registerComponent: function (component) {
    console.log('registering\tid\t' + component['id']);
    if (component['id'].indexOf('tab-') > -1) {
        console.log("tab getting user timeout event handler\t" + component['id']);
        component.on('userTimeOut', this.onUserTimeOut);
    }
    return true;
},
```

This is the `onUserTimeOut` handler:

```
onUserTimeOut: function (caller) {
    console.log('user-time-out\tid' + this['id'] + '\tcaller-id\t' + caller['id']);
}
```

And I have this code in the main controller called by a button click. Confirmed it does get called as well:

```
fireUserTimeOut: function(button) {
    console.log('fireUserTimeOut\t' + button['id']);
    Ext.GlobalEvents.fireEvent('userTimeOut', button);
},
```

Searching the web, I have tried numerous approaches instead of `Ext.GlobalEvents`, but no luck. Eventually, I want to be able to have any entity: component, data store, application, view, etc. act as a listener and be able to broadcast the event and have it acted upon.

I can get it to work with built-in events like `click` or `focus`, but not these custom events.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: you have to get the component and fire the event. because your registering events with the compoenents

Comment: That kind of sucks. The whole point of events and listeners is that you don't know who is listening, just say something happened and let the listeners figure it out. If I have to keep track of who the listeners are, I might as well bypass the event and just call the handler directly?

Comment: That would be a pretty memory leak if all events were global after registering them on controls. And listening and firing are two different things you are mixing up.

Comment: @Tarabass - they're clear in my mind; I can see because I was using `component` everywhere (consequence of ctrl-C + ctrl-V) that it might look like I was confused; have cleaned up the sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
component.on('userTimeOut', this.onUserTimeOut);
```

Use:

```
Ext.GlobalEvents.on('userTimeOut', this.onUserTimeOut, component);
```

Then you can call `fireEvent` as you are doing. In your `onUserTimeOut` you can access the component acting on the event via `this`, e.g. `this.id`.

Comment: Thank you, works amazing! I get ACKs from every component!